# Amazon Payment Method will not show up in frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, amazon

I've installed the [Amazon Payment](https://github.com/amzn/amazon-payments-magento-plugin) Plugin and configured it properly in backend. But for some reason it won't show up in frontend at all. I reviewed the logs but these are empty.
Can anyone point me in the right direction where to start debugging? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be caused by various reasons.

1. Make sure following function returns true:
   Amazon_Payments_Model_Config::isEnabled()
2. `CheckoutAmazonSession` must exists to process Amazon Payments. Therefore you need to be logged in what means you need to show the Amazon login button somewhere, for example on Checkout: `amazon_payments/onepage/button.phtml`

Search for a node called "checkout.onepage.login" or "checkout_onepage_index" in the layout update files. Check if the child/block did not get removed or overwritten. Maybe you want to implement the button directly in your custom layout (if exists):

```
<block type="amazon_payments/button" name="amazonpaymentsbutton" template="amazon_payments/onepage/button.phtml"/>
```